# Redirect not logged in users but exclude 1 page

Tags: wp-redirect

I have the below code in the header.php to redirect not logged in users to the home page and it works great but a bit to well as it stops not logged in people accessing the terms and conditions that is linked to in the footer. It doesnt even allow them to click on the links so they look like just normal text. Does anyone have any suggestions how to exclude one page from the redirect?

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
wp_redirect( 'https://website.com');
exit;
} ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/424035/simple-way-to-make-most-of-my-site-private/424043#424043